# SQL index with parent child design

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, index-tuning

I am looking to understand a typical approach to indexes in a database parent-child design. This is a basic financial calculator for calculating complex commissions used monthly and driven by stored procedures.

Currently, the base number of transactions driving this is about 400,000 rows. Every month this increases approximately 3-5%. Each transaction may have 1-5 (average of 3) commission records stored, meaning that each month a million records or more are inserted into the below tables.

Often, commission is run and deleted multiple times depending on analysts adjustments.

**Environment:** SQL Server 2016 standard, 32Gb memory, 8 cpu cores

**Design:**

> **transaction_mstr** - Table that stores each commission run date, period, and user details (who ran it, what date and time, etc.)
> **transaction_map** - Table that stores every account being commission in the period
> **transaction_hdr** - Table that stores every transaction associated with the account
> **transaction_dtl** - Table that stores commission details per transaction

**Keys**

> transaction_mstr: id
> transaction_map: id, mstr_id
> transaction_hdr: id, mstr_id, map_id
> transaction_dtl: id, mstr_id, map_id, hdr_id

Simple Query to illustrate the relationships:

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction_mstr a
     JOIN transaction_map b ON a.id = b.mstr_id
     JOIN transaction_hdr c ON b.id = c.map_id
     JOIN transaction_dtl d ON c.id = d.hdr_id;
```

**Current keys**

> The ID column in each table is a primary key (unique auto increment value). 
> A single foreign key is created on each table relating referencing the parent primary key.

**The Ask**
In it's current state, inserting and deleting commission from the hdr and dtl tables is very slow. I have asked the infrastructure team to ensure the environment is resourced appropriately, but I'd like to understand if a better key design would improve performance.

In addition, I have narrowed down the wait time to the actual insert and delete. The calculations run rather quickly (3-5 mins), but the inserts into the various tables take upwards of 30 minutes. The deletes take approximately 20 mins per commission period.

**Create table / index scripts**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction_dtl](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mstr_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [map_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [hdr_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [trx_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [trx_parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [agent_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [rate_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [frequency_id] [tinyint] NULL,
    [period_days] [tinyint] NULL,
    [commission] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [row_create_ts] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transaction_dtl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mstr_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [map_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [trx_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [trx_parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [trx_other_id] [int] NULL,
    [level] [tinyint] NULL,
    [days_held] [smallint] NULL,
    [units_bal] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [reversal] [int] NULL,
    [sortkey] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [row_create_ts] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transaction_hdr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mstr_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [fund_id] [tinyint] NULL,
    [account_id] [int] NULL,
    [wholesaler_id] [int] NULL,
    [unbalanced] [bit] NULL,
    [nobalance] [bit] NULL,
    [row_create_ts] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transaction_map] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction_mstr](
    [id] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [caller_sid] [varbinary](85) NOT NULL,
    [caller_name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [start_time] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [end_time] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [commission_type] [tinyint] NULL,
    [commission_date] [date] NULL,
    [run_date] [date] NULL,
    [frequency_id] [tinyint] NULL,
    [closed] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [row_create_ts] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [row_modified_ts] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transaction_mstr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_dtl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_commission_dtl_row_create_ts]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [row_create_ts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_hdr_reversal]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [reversal]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_commission_hdr_row_create_ts]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [row_create_ts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_map_balanced]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [unbalanced]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_map_nobalance]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [nobalance]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_commission_map_row_create_ts]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [row_create_ts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_mstr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_master_closed]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [closed]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_mstr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_master_create_row_ts]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [row_create_ts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_dtl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_dtl_hdr] FOREIGN KEY([hdr_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[transaction_hdr] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_dtl] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_dtl_hdr]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_hdr_map] FOREIGN KEY([map_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[transaction_map] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_hdr_map]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_map_mstr] FOREIGN KEY([mstr_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[transaction_mstr] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_map_mstr]
GO
```

**Cascading Deletes**

I have been on the fence about using cascading deletes. I can easily enough script this, but thought it might be useful for referential integrity.

**Updated Index Code** (slowed performance significantly)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction_dtl](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mstr_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [map_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [hdr_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [trx_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [trx_parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [agent_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [rate_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [frequency_id] [tinyint] NULL,
    [period_days] [tinyint] NULL,
    [commission] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [row_create_ts] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transaction_dtl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [mstr_id] ASC,
    [map_id] ASC,
    [hdr_id] ASC,
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mstr_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [map_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [trx_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [trx_parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [trx_other_id] [int] NULL,
    [level] [tinyint] NULL,
    [days_held] [smallint] NULL,
    [units_bal] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [reversal] [int] NULL,
    [sortkey] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [row_create_ts] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transaction_hdr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [mstr_id] ASC,
    [map_id] ASC,
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mstr_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fund_id] [tinyint] NULL,
    [account_id] [int] NULL,
    [wholesaler_id] [int] NULL,
    [unbalanced] [bit] NULL,
    [nobalance] [bit] NULL,
    [row_create_ts] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transaction_map] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [mstr_id] ASC,
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction_mstr](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [caller_sid] [varbinary](85) NOT NULL,
    [caller_name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [start_time] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [end_time] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [commission_type] [tinyint] NULL,
    [commission_date] [date] NULL,
    [run_date] [date] NULL,
    [frequency_id] [tinyint] NULL,
    [closed] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [row_create_ts] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [row_modified_ts] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transaction_mstr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_dtl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_commission_dtl_row_create_ts]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [row_create_ts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_hdr_reversal]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [reversal]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_commission_hdr_row_create_ts]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [row_create_ts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_map_balanced]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [unbalanced]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_map_nobalance]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [nobalance]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_commission_map_row_create_ts]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [row_create_ts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_mstr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_master_closed]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [closed]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_mstr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_transaction_master_create_row_ts]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [row_create_ts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_dtl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_dtl_transaction_hdr] FOREIGN KEY([mstr_id], [map_id], [hdr_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[transaction_hdr] ([mstr_id], [map_id], [id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_dtl] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_dtl_transaction_hdr]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_hdr_transaction_map] FOREIGN KEY([mstr_id], [map_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[transaction_map] ([mstr_id], [id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_hdr] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_hdr_transaction_map]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_map_transaction_mstr] FOREIGN KEY([mstr_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[transaction_mstr] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[transaction_map] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_transaction_map_transaction_mstr]
GO
```

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements and all `CREATE INDEX` statements. Also. Describe how you're doing the `INSERT`s. A system half that powerful should be able to add 1M rows to each table in <5m.

Comment: Agreed with Michael, your runtimes seem suspiciously slow. Knowing what resources your server is provisioned with would be helpful (feel free to update the post once you hear back from your infrastructure team), but that's not likely the issue. I'm addition to your Table and Index definitions (as Michael asked for), please provide the exact `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements you're using, as those will determine what the proper indexing should be (and may also provide a clue why your queries are running so slow). Even your calculations taking minutes on a table that size seems under-performant.

Comment: @J.D. Will update with table and index scripts. The primary calculation is very complicated and required the use of a recursive query. I am confident in the query that drives the result sets, and the time it takes for those to complete. When I run the calculation scripts to screen("SELECT"), they complete in full in a few minutes. As soon as I "INSERT INTO X" table, I see 20-30 minute wait times.

Comment: Well here's some perspective, recursion in SQL Server can be very performant. I've repeatedly ran recursive calculations on tables with ~1,000,000 rows in about 1 second total runtime, on modest hardware. To take minutes on the amount of data you're talking is either indicative of the same problem your DML queries are facing, or indicative of the way you architected your calculation queries possibly not being the most efficient relational implementation, such as using a cursor instead of a recursive CTE. Without knowing your calculation queries though, I can only assume it might be the former.

Comment: @J.D. I’m using a recursive CTE. Again, this component runs with a reasonable duration and it’s not really the focus of the question. (Though, I’m sure there is opportunity to improve it)

Comment: Sure thing, I don't mean to harp on it, rather just saying it could be correlative to your main issue as well, or maybe not. Could you also please include your `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements, and their correlating actual execution plans (you can upload the plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.BrentOzar.com/PasteThePlan) and then link them in your post)?

Comment: @J.D. Here is a link to a basic query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJTR8Ccwt

Comment: @warrenk Is that your `DELETE` and `INSERT` query?

Comment: @J.D. just a select, which is less performant now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's right way to store parent/child hierarchies.

Put the ID for each child table at the end, so each table has a Primary Key clustered index where the parent key is the leading columns. eg the primary keys should be:

```
transaction_mstr: id
transaction_map:  mstr_id, id
transaction_hdr:  mstr_id, map_id, id
transaction_dtl:  mstr_id, map_id, hdr_id, id
```

That way all the child rows for each parent are stored together, and there's an index that supports efficient lookup of a child from a parent, and prevents a full table scan when deleting a parent row.

But with compound keys, you need to join using the full foreign key.  eg

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction_mstr a
     JOIN transaction_map b 
        ON b.mstr_id = a.id
     JOIN transaction_hdr c 
        ON  c.mstr_id = b.mstr_id
        AND c.map_id = c.id
     JOIN transaction_dtl d 
        ON d.mstr_id = c.mstr_id 
        AND d.map_id = c.map_id
        AND d.hdr_id = c.id
```

Comment: In case map/hdr/dtl rows are going to be referred to directly, not via parent relationships, then you will want a non-clustered unique index on `id` for each too. In fact even without that requirement you possibly want a unique constraint/index on `id` anyway to guard against bugs breaking that bit of data integrity — so perhaps have `id` as a non-clustered primary key in each case and the compound keys as above as the clustering keys. This will increase storage requirements, as the NCI will contain the other columns from the CI too, but data integrity is usually far more important than that.

Comment: With the primary key's defined as above, would any foreign keys be required? (As per David Browne)

Comment: Yes.  Foreign Keys are still required, but you don’t need additional indexes to support them. As the PK plays that role too.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Do you recommend the cascading deletes?

Comment: In general, yes, but in a performance-critical scenario you may want to delete-and-commit child rows directly rather than relying on the cascading behavior.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I made your recommended changes and my performance got significantly worse. (doubled in length to execute). I've updated the original post with the new index code, perhaps you can review and confirm it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Yes the indexes look good. Can you paste a query plan for a typical query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131349/discussion-between-warrenk-and-david-browne-microsoft).

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJTR8Ccwt

Comment: See updated answer.  You need to join along the FKs.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for the update, query performance improved! On another note, I realize I need to utilize partitioning to manage these datasets due to size. I’d like to keep the most recent 4 quarters on primary disk and archive / move older datasets to another file group on cheaper disk. The two tables I’d like to partition are transaction_hdr and transaction_dtl by mstr_id. Would doing this mean I’d have to adjust keys yet again?

Comment: You can seamlessly partition by any clustered index key column.  So mstr_id would work fine.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft digging an old one up for you. I've partitioned the transaction_dtl table for simpler swapping. I have a clustered index on the partition key "mstr_id". I wanted to create a unique index on "id" on the transaction_dtl table as it's a foreign key to transaction hdr, but I need to include the partition key so the index would be on "mstr_id" and "id". This seems redundant, do you have a better recommendation?

Comment: I don't understand.  The Foreign Key to transaction_hdr would be on `transaction_dtl(mstr_id, map_id, hdr_id) -> transaction_hdr(mstr_id, map_id, id).`

Comment: I didn't explain that well. You are correct regarding the foreign keys, but should there not be an index on the transaction_dtl (id) field as it's the only column with unique values in the table? (Or is does the PK take care of that?)

Comment: Does it really matter if two rows have the same id, as long as they have different (mstr_id,map_id,hdr_id)?  You can't partition a unique index on id on mstr_id.  You can partition a non-unique index, if you just have a lookup scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to find your query in Query_Store and see the recommended index. Any way I can bet on the fact that you have triggers (probably for audit) on your tables or million of unused indexes. There is no over possible explanation for such timings.

Comment: No triggers at all. With the indexes I mentioned in my first post already created, the query_store has no other recommended indexes.